# jquery same action on different element on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have a product boxes in which i want to apply hover which show add to cart button so i need a jquery which apply on different boxes. my html code is...

```
<div class="col-md-3 product-tabs-1">
    <div class="col-md-12 product-img product-img-1 no-pad-lf"> <img src="assets/img/shop/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <span class="sale-btn">Sale!</span>
        <div class="add-cart-btn add-cart-btn-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary cart-btn">Add To Cart</button> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-pad-lf">
        <h5>BRUSH</h5> <span class="pull-left sale-price">£15.00 </span><span class="pull-left">&nbsp £12.00</span><span class="pull-right"><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i><i class="far fa-star"></i></span> </div>
</div>
```

My script on single element is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        $('.product-img-' + i).hover(function() {
            $('.add-cart-btn').fadeToggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `.add-cart-btn` button is child element of div that has hover event, You can find it in hover elements contexts(`this`) to find child element in it:

```
$('.product-img').hover(function(){
  $('.add-cart-btn',this).fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the child of current element, Use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target it.

Additionally you don't need `for` loop to attach event handlers it can be achieved using [Class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) using a common CSS class i.e. `product-img`

```
$('.product-img').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('.add-cart-btn').fadeToggle();
});
```